When using Pandas json_normalize function, in the JSON i passed for some of the sections "record_path" not exists
I have JSON data as follows:
json_data = [
    {
        "meta_info": {"id": 1, "name": "Alice"},
        "data": [{"value": 100}, {"value": 200}]
    },
    {
        "meta_info": {"id": 2, "name": "Bob"},
        "data": []
    },
    {
        "meta_info": {"id": 3, "name": "Charlie"}
        # "data" key is missing
    }
]

When I try to read it into a pd.DataFrame with pd.json_normalize:
df = pd.json_normalize(json_data, record_path='data', meta=['meta_info.id', 'meta_info.name'], errors='ignore') 

I am getting the error:
KeyError: "Key 'data' not found. If specifying a record_path, all elements of data should have the path.

Based on json_data input above, my desired output as a dataframe looks like this:



value
meta_info.id
meta_info.name




100.0
1
Alice


200.0
1
Alice


NaN
2
Bob


NaN
3
Charlie




For this, you should iterate through the data in python (json_normalize is not flexible enough to cover this):
contents = []

for dictionary in json_data:
    meta_info = dictionary['meta_info']
    values = dictionary.get('data')
    if not values:
        values = [{'value':None}]
    values = [entry|meta_info for entry in values]
    contents.extend(values)

pd.DataFrame(contents)
   value  id     name
0  100.0   1    Alice
1  200.0   1    Alice
2    NaN   2      Bob
3    NaN   3  Charlie


Thanks but I cannot hard code the values, both the meta an record_path value is read at run time from Front End Application and the Json Structure also changes each time when provided input from the Font End application.
Basically I am looking for an approach can work with distinct Json files with requirement of chnaging code.

One approach could be to correct json_data before passing it to pd.json_normalize. Showing 2 options depending on python version (>= 3.5, >= 3.9):
Python 3.5
Since python 3.5 (examples at PEP 448), we can update via dictionary unpacking (**):
data = [
        {**d,
         **{'data': [{'value': np.nan}] 
            if d.get('data', []) == []
            else d.get('data')
            }
         } 
        for d in json_data
        ]

out = pd.json_normalize(data=data, 
                        record_path='data', 
                        meta=[['meta_info', 'id'], ['meta_info', 'name']]
                        )

Output:
   value meta_info.id meta_info.name
0  100.0            1          Alice
1  200.0            1          Alice
2    NaN            2            Bob
3    NaN            3        Charlie

Explanation
The value for our "update" dict (i.e., **{'data': ..} we determine as follows:

For each dict (d), we try dict.get and default to [], thus aligning dicts without 'data' key (your 3rd dict) with the dicts that have {'data': []} (your 2nd dict).
Now we check if the value equals [], if so, we overwrite with [{'value': np.nan}] (now applicable to both 2nd and 3rd dict), else we just keep the value as is (1st dict).
The logic of {**d, **{'data': ...}} is that the later values (i.e. the right dict) will update the left values (the left dict). Doing this inside a for loop, for each d in json_data, we get the intermediate result:

# data

[{'meta_info': {'id': 1, 'name': 'Alice'},
  'data': [{'value': 100}, {'value': 200}]},
 {'meta_info': {'id': 2, 'name': 'Bob'}, 'data': [{'value': nan}]},
 {'meta_info': {'id': 3, 'name': 'Charlie'}, 'data': [{'value': nan}]}]


This we can correctly pass to pd.json_normalize. Make sure to add meta fields correctly. Not: meta=['meta_info.id', ...], but: meta=[['meta_info','id'], ...].

Python 3.9
Since python 3.9 (examples at PEP 584) we can create data using the dict merge operator (|):
data = [d 
        if d.get('data', []) != [] 
        else d | {'data': [{'value': np.nan}]} 
        for d in json_data
        ]

# pd.json_normalize(data, ...) -> same result


In this case, we keep d if d.get('data', []) != [] (1st dict), else we update d with {'data': [{'value': np.nan}]} via d | {'data': [{'value': np.nan}]} (2nd and 3rd dict).


Thanks but I cannot hard code the values, both the meta an record_path value is read at run time from Front End Application and the Json Structure also changes each time when provided input from the Font End application.
Basically I am looking for an approach can work with distinct Json files with requirement of chnaging code.

Right, so what part is stable? Is record_path at least always called data? In correct form, is it always max [{"value": 100},{"value2": 1}], or could it be nested [{"value": 100},{"value2": {"id": 1, ...}]? As for meta is it always called meta_info? Please add info on the elements that are stable or certainly unstable to your post (not here in the comments; edit the post), otherwise we could be dealing with just about anything.
